# Pylance reports incorrect error for openpyxl

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, mypy, pylance

I'm using VSCode for python and am getting a typing error with Pylance that appears incorrect and is not reported as an error by `mypy --strict`.

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook("c:/temp/file.xlsx")
ws = wb["Sheet1"]
x = ws["A1"]
```

Pylance reports `"__getitem__" method not defined on type "Chartsheet"` for `ws["A1"]`.  mypy reports `Success: no issues found in 1 source file`

How can I get Pylance to behave better, other than `#type: ignore`? Or should I just use `mypy` instead?

Comment: Well, have you checked? Does the type returned by `load_workbook` implement the `__getitem__` method? Does the type returned by _that_ implement `__getitem__`? If so, you are doing everything right and Pylance is wrong. It may be worth opening an issue for this.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg  The code works. `ws["A1"]` is the preferred way to access a cell. https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html  And yes, `worksheet.py` includes `def __getitem__(self, key)`.

Comment: But it seems to think that the type returned is `Chartsheet`. Maybe that is the issue. Mypy supports `reveal_locals()` to show types of the variables in the surrounding scope. Maybe you can try that with pylance too and see, what it _thinks_ `wb` and `ws` are and compare that to what they actually are (using `type(wb)` and `type(ws)`).

Comment: It appears the problem is that I installed `openpyxl-stubs`, which mypy wants but which causes Pylance to generate the error.  You can right click on an import and `Go To Declaration` which shows the file where the function is declared.  `openpyxl-stubs` has a return type of `Workbook` while uninstalling it shows a declaration without a return type, which is interpreted as `Any`, so no error.  With the `stubs` file `mypy` is happy, without it `Pylance` is happy.

Comment: Hi foosion, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the problem is that I installed `openpyxl-stubs`, which `mypy` wants but which causes `Pylance` to generate the error. You can right click on an import and `Go To Declaration` which shows the file where the function is declared. `openpyxl-stubs` has a return type of `Workbook` while uninstalling it shows a declaration without a return type, which is interpreted as `Any`, so no error (but no real typechecking). With the `stubs` file `mypy` is happy, without it `Pylance` is happy